# Deleted Template Variables (created via Low Variables) keep reappearing

Tags: ee3, low-variables, global-variables

http://recordit.co/R8eImfvLyP

EE3 with Low Variables installed. I created a bunch of variables in both EE and Low Variables only to try to remove them. They are showing in the Template Variable area and Low Variables. When I delete them via the CP, or files they reappear and the files are recreated.

I've tried uninstalling the plugin and removing files, to removing files and uninstalling the plugin. Turning off LV save as files and sync options.

Answer (score 1):

Low Variables extends the native Template Variables, so for every LV, there is a TV. Just leave 'em and if you need to delete them, do so via LV.